# How to implement alignment through traceback for Levenshtein edit distance

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, levenshtein-distance

So I have successfully implemented the Levenshtein (edit minimum distance) algorithm with the help of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and this [Needleman](https://kraulis.se/lectures/molbioinfo2001/dynprog/dynamic.html) tutorial, whereby custom, insertion and deletion cost 1, and substitution/replacement cost 2.

Executable gist https://gist.github.com/axelmukwena/8696ec4ec72849d3cf384f5d97321407

```
import numpy as np

def word_edit_distance(x, y):
    rows = len(x) + 1
    cols = len(y) + 1
    distance = np.zeros((rows, cols), dtype=int)

    for i in range(1, rows):
        for k in range(1, cols):
            distance[i][0] = i
            distance[0][k] = k

    for col in range(1, cols):
        for row in range(1, rows):
            if x[row - 1] == y[col - 1]:
                cost = 0
            else:
                cost = 2
            distance[row][col] = min(distance[row - 1][col] + 1,
                                     distance[row][col - 1] + 1,
                                     distance[row - 1][col - 1] + cost)
     
    print(backtrace(x, y, distance))
    edit_distance = distance[row][col]
    return edit_distance, distance


result = word_edit_distance("AACGCA", "GAGCTA")
print(result[0])
print(result[1])
```

```
# output
4
[[0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
 [1 2 1 2 3 4 5]
 [2 3 2 3 4 5 4]
 [3 4 3 4 3 4 5]
 [4 3 4 3 4 5 6]
 [5 4 5 4 3 4 5]
 [6 5 4 5 4 5 4]]
```

> And, I somehow also understand how to compute the backtracking, see my attempt below. However, there is a slight error. See Bottom

```
def backtrace(first, second, matrix):
    f = [char for char in first]
    s = [char for char in second]
    new_f, new_s = [], []
    row = len(f)
    col = len(s)
    trace = [[row, col]]

    while True:
        a = matrix[row - 1][col]
        b = matrix[row - 1][col - 1]
        c = matrix[row][col - 1]

        which = min(a, b, c)

        if which == matrix[row][col] or which == matrix[row][col] - 2:
            # when diagonal backtrace substitution or no substitution
            trace.append([row - 1, col - 1])
            new_f = [f[row - 1]] + new_f
            new_s = [s[col - 1]] + new_s

            row, col = row - 1, col - 1

        elif which == matrix[row][col] - 1:
            # either deletion or insertion, find if minimum is up or left
            if which == matrix[row - 1][col]:
                trace.append([row - 1, col])
                new_f = [f[row - 1]] + new_f
                new_s = ["-"] + new_s

                row, col = row - 1, col

            elif which == matrix[row][col - 1]:
                trace.append([row, col - 1])
                new_f = ["-"] + new_f
                new_s = [s[col - 1]] + new_s

                row, col = row, col - 1

        # Exit the loop
        if row == 0 or col == 0:
            return trace, new_f, new_s
```

Outcome

```
# trace => [[6, 6], [5, 5], [5, 4], [4, 3], [3, 2], [2, 2], [1, 2], [0, 1]]
['A', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'C', '-', 'A'], ['A', '-', '-', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'A']
```

Expected outcome:

```
# trace => [[6, 6], [5, 5], [5, 4], [4, 3], [3, 2], [2, 2], [1, 1], [0, 0]]
['A', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'C', '-', 'A'], ['A', 'A', '-', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'A']
```

---

> Whats happening is:

1. During finding edit distance,

```
# cost = 2
distance[row - 1][col] + 1 = 2         # orange
distance[row][col - 1] + 1 = 4         # yellow
distance[row - 1][col - 1] + cost = 2  # green
```

So here, both orange and green are candidates. But the ideal candidate is green because `A == A`

[image]

2. During backtracking, the we don't have information about the sequences, just the points in the matrix. So the trace will get the lowest of the three...

```
a = matrix[row - 1][col]      # a = 1
b = matrix[row - 1][col - 1]  # b = 2
c = matrix[row][col - 1]      # c = 3

which = min(a, b, c)          # which = a instead of b
```

[image]

---

Am I even using the correct backtracing algorithm?

Comment: It should not be MIN, you should select the current where cost is equal to cost of other node + cost of operation from other node to the current node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not be `min(a,b,c)`. You should select the node that minimizes the score of the other node plus cost of operation from the other node to the current one.

```
r = matrix[row][col]          # current node
a = matrix[row - 1][col]      # a = 1
b = matrix[row - 1][col - 1]  # b = 2
c = matrix[row][col - 1]      # c = 3

if x[row - 1] == y[col - 1]:
    cost = 0
else:
    cost = 2

if r == a + 1: return a
if r == b + cost: return b
if r == c + 1: return c
```

or in a more compressed form:

```
which = min(a + 1, b + cost, c + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @tstanisl 's answer, here is my integrated implementation:

```
def backtrace(first, second, matrix):
    f = [char for char in first]
    s = [char for char in second]
    new_f, new_s = [], []
    row = len(f)
    col = len(s)
    trace = [[row, col]]

    while True:
        if f[row - 1] == s[col - 1]:
            cost = 0
        else:
            cost = 2

        r = matrix[row][col]
        a = matrix[row - 1][col]
        b = matrix[row - 1][col - 1]
        c = matrix[row][col - 1]

        if r == b + cost:
            # when diagonal backtrace substitution or no substitution
            trace.append([row - 1, col - 1])
            new_f = [f[row - 1]] + new_f
            new_s = [s[col - 1]] + new_s

            row, col = row - 1, col - 1

        else:
            # either deletion or insertion, find if minimum is up or left
            if r == a + 1:
                trace.append([row - 1, col])
                new_f = [f[row - 1]] + new_f
                new_s = ["-"] + new_s

                row, col = row - 1, col

            elif r == c + 1:
                trace.append([row, col - 1])
                new_f = ["-"] + new_f
                new_s = [s[col - 1]] + new_s

                row, col = row, col - 1

        # Exit the loop
        if row == 0 or col == 0:
            return trace, new_f, new_s
```